# interrupt in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, power-management

I have taken one gpio of my omap4 based custom board as input gpio. When I connect any external h/w on any port then input gpio gets pull down and I get interrupt on that gpio.

Now when I run Linux kernel 2.6 its working fine and gets interrupt on that gpio but when I use Linux kernel 3.0, its not creating interrupt on that gpio. The value of that gpio doesn't change and interrupt handler is not called.

So is there any difference in power level setting for creating interrupt in Linux kernel?

Comment: Can you share the code ?

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/pinctrl.txt

Comment: Are you registering the handler for these interrupts or relying on the defaults? Are they level or edge triggered?

Comment: It's probably a pull down or pull up resistor activated by the kernel

Comment: @Mellowcandle yea you are right. In 2.6 kernel in board file it was getting pull up and in 3.0 kernel that was not..!!

Comment: @Mellowcandle let's put that in an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue was resolved by correctly specifying the pull-up on the pin.

One more thing to consider usually is the "**pin-mux**" i.e. one would need to verify that the pin in question is configured as a GPIO and not some other functionality.

A detailed description of the pin configuration,
specifically for OMAP4 (mux, pull, wake-up), is available [**here**](http://www.slideshare.net/joujiahe/introduction-to-omap4-pad-configuration).